# SignalR + Mapping Global.asax HttpContext to Startup.cs

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, owin

How to map HttpContext.Application between Global.asax and Startup.cs and use it in a SignalR hub

*Global.asax*

```
public void Application_Start()
{
    var CoolObj = new CoolClass();
    this.Application.Add("CoolObj", CoolObj);
}
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

*MyHub*

```
Context.Request.GetHttpContext().Application("CoolObj")
```

Will always return a null reference exception

What is the correct way to get the "CoolObj" in the hub while not breaking other areas that access it from the HttpContext.Current ?